# Kendo-dropdown unit test in angular with Jasmine

Tags: angular, kendo-dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to use Jasmine/Karma to run integration test on my angular application. We are predominantly using the kendo controls in the application. When writing a test suite to test the kendo drop down component where I am unable to get the reference of the kendo dropdown control in the spec file. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ],
      imports:[HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule,FormsModule ,ReactiveFormsModule ],
      providers:[ WebApiService,YYYY,ZZZZ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateCustomerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    datePipe=new DatePipe("en-US");
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('#should the length of dropdown is greater than one',()=>{
    const trigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#dropDownId')).nativeElement;
    expect(trigger).toBeTruthy();
   
  });

html
<kendo-floatinglabel
  [text]="Customer"
>
  <kendo-dropdownlist
    [id]="'dropDownId'"
    [data]="DataItems"
    [textField]="'DataText'"
    [valueField]="'DataValue'"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
    
  >
  </kendo-dropdownlist>

</kendo-floatinglabel>
```

The test is breaking due to undefined value in the trigger variable.

Comment: You have strange css selector

Comment: Hi, I am very new to the unit testing. could you please tell me what is the best way to use selector. thanks

Comment: `.#dropDownId` there is not such selector. You should either use class selector `.dropDownId` or id selector `#dropDownId`

Comment: oh my bad. that was a typo error. I was using #dropDownId only. thanks

Comment: Can you include html of your component? Also, have you tried to call ` fixture.detectChanges();` before getting trigger element?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have added the control used in the html and also I am doing th fixture.detectChanges(). Do i need to give the kendo modules as reference in my spec file.

Comment: `[id]="dropDownId"` here `dropDownId` is a component property not a string. If you want it to be a static string then write `id="dropDownId"`

Comment: I have modified but still my control object is undefined in the spec. Do i need to import any kendo components in the providers of my test suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the import of the Kendo controls module. Here's what worked for me.

```
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
```

Then add `InputsModule` to the list of `imports` in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` module definition:

```
imports:[InputsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
```